ASP.NET Webforms to ASP.NET Core Razor pages
I have a handful of ASP.NET Webforms I need to start converting to ASP.NET Core Razor pages.
Below I have an example on how one of these pages currently operates to give an idea of what I am working with, but I am unsure on where to even begin with converting this all to Razor pages. I am open to other solutions
HTML
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Device Name or Number" id="searchval" />
<div class="input-group-append">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="search()"></button>
<span id="number"></span>
<span id="name"></span>
<span id="model"></span>

JavaScript
function search() {
  var device = $('searchval').val();

  $.ajax({
     url: "postback.aspx",
     data: {
         ftn: 1, 
         val: device
     },
     success: function (data) {
       var splitdata = data.split(";");
       var number = $.trim(splitdata[0]);
       var name = $.trim(splitdata[1]);
       var model = $.trim(splitdata[2]);

       $("#number").text(number);
       $("#name").text(name);
       $("#model").text(model);
     }
  });
}

postback.aspx.cs C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Function = Request.QueryString["ftn"];

    switch (Function)
    {
       case "1":
         Search();
         break;

       default:
         break;
    }
}

public void Search()
{
   string value = Request.QueryString["val"];
   string sqlstring = /*connection string here*/;

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
   con.Open();

   string qry = /*stored procedure using value*/

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

   using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (sdr.Read())
     {
       string number = sdr.["devnumber"].ToString();
       string name = sdr.["devname"].ToString();
       string model = sdr.["devmodel"].ToString();

       Response.Write(number);
       Response.Write(";");
       Response.Write(name);
       Response.Write(";");
       Response.Write(model);
     }
   }
   con.Close();
}

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET Core Razor pages and have done the documented tutorial from Microsoft, but I am just struggling on how to apply that to converting this current app I am working with.

Is it an external requirement to migrate to razor pages? I'd go for MVC as it's more mainstream

might be easier to leave the front end alone and use .net core web api, then you just need to change your endpoint from like postback.aspx to your api controller

+1 for the suggestion by @WiktorZychla, you could do this in stages too. Start by migrating to ASP.NET MVC first and then migrate to ASP.NET Core. The steps would be much more manageable and easier to perform. Yes, there some challenges migrating ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core (MVC) but they are definitely smaller than going directly from ASP.NET Web Forms on .NET Standard to ASP.NET Core Razor Pages on .NET Core.

Thanks for the suggestion @WiktorZychla I was looking at Razor Pages as my understanding was that it was more suitable for single page applications such as this one. However, looking at the MVC and especially the suggeestion about doing this is stages from Web Forms > ASP.NET MVC > ASP.NET Core (MVC) that might be more manageable

For Single-Page-Application I think you meant "Blazor" not "Razor".  You might also consider just Angular or React front-end and standard API-style backend.  With Blazor you'll have all the overhead of putting .NET into WASM.  Visual Studio includes project types for all three....

could you try using the https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant tool to convert the application code. here is the link you can refer for more detail https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant

Razor Pages is a great choice for migrating a Web Forms app because the underlying principal is the same - they are both page-focussed development frameworks. And the learning curve for Razor Pages is a lot lower than that for MVC (which is mainly why Razor Pages was introduced).
You will obviously have to learn the framework, either way, but with Razor Pages, there are some one-to-one mappings to help you:

The Razor cshtml file maps to the Web Forms aspx file. Both serve the role of View Template
The PageModel class file maps to the aspx.cs code-behind file. Both serve the role of Page Controller.

The Page_Load request handling method in a Web Forms app is replaced by HTTP method-specific handler methods in Razor Pages - OnGet, OnPost, OnDelete etc.
Model binding to public properties on the PageModel class replace the need to reference the Request collections (Form, QueryString) directly.
